# Go to next fieldset from jquery modal based on AJAX response code

Tags: jquery, ajax, modal-dialog, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I'm sending an GET AJAX call to Mailchimp from a JQuery modal with this scripts. How do i pass the user to the next fieldset if server response is succesful? Do i need to do it from the first javascript posted here or from the php code? I'm sorry for the long display below.

JS:

```
  $('#reg_btn').on('click', function(){
      $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: 'subscribe.php',
              dataType: 'json',
              data: {
                email: $('# .email').val(),
              },
              success: function(response) {
                // User has been successfully subscribed
                // Do something here
              },
              error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                 var response = $.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText);

                 // User has not been subscribed
                // Show an error or do something else here  
             }

            });

      e.preventDefault();
      return false;
  });
```

PHP:

```
    include 'Mailchimp.php';
    use \DrewM\MailChimp\MailChimp;
    $MailChimp = new MailChimp('your**api***key');
    $response = [];
    $list_id = 'list_id_goes_here';

    function emailExistsMc($subscriberMail, $list_id){
        global $MailChimp;
        $subscriber_hash = $MailChimp->subscriberHash($subscriberMail);
        $result = $MailChimp->get("lists/$list_id/members/$subscriber_hash");
        if($result['status'] == '404') return false;
        return true;
    }
```

And finally my MODAL HTML+JS script:

```
    <button type="submit" onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" > HERE IS MY BUTTON </button>
        <!-- multistep form -->
        <div id="id01" class="modalx modalx-style_set">
        <form id="msform">
        <!-- progressbar -->
        <ul id="progressbar">
        <li class="active">LOG IN</li>
        <li>TERMS</li>
        <li>INFO</li>
        </ul>
        <!-- fieldsets -->
        <fieldset>
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
        <input type="text" name="code" placeholder="Promo Code" />
        <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
        <input type="text" name="address" placeholder="Complete address" minlength="42" maxlength="42" />
        <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Back" />
        <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
        <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Back" />
        </fieldset>
        </form>

       <script>
       //jQuery time
       $(document).ready(function(){
         var modalx = document.getElementById('id01');

         // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
         window.onclick = function(event) {
             if (event.target == modalx) {
                 modalx.style.display = "none";
             }
         }

       var current_fs, next_fs, previous_fs; //fieldsets
       var left, opacity, scale; //fieldset properties which we will animate
       var animating; //flag to prevent quick multi-click glitches

       $(".next").click(function(){
         if(animating) return false;
         animating = true;

         current_fs = $(this).parent();
         next_fs = $(this).parent().next();

         //activate next step on progressbar using the index of next_fs
         $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");

         //show the next fieldset
         next_fs.show();
         //hide the current fieldset with style
         current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
           step: function(now, mx) {
             //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
             //1. scale current_fs down to 80%
             scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
             //2. bring next_fs from the right(50%)
             left = (now * 50)+"%";
             //3. increase opacity of next_fs to 1 as it moves in
             opacity = 1 - now;
             current_fs.css({'transform': 'scale('+scale+')'});
             next_fs.css({'left': left, 'opacity': opacity});
           },
           duration: 800,
           complete: function(){
             current_fs.hide();
             animating = false;
           },
           //this comes from the custom easing plugin
           easing: 'easeInOutBack'
         });
       });

       $(".previous").click(function(){
         if(animating) return false;
         animating = true;

         current_fs = $(this).parent();
         previous_fs = $(this).parent().prev();

         //de-activate current step on progressbar
         $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(current_fs)).removeClass("active");

         //show the previous fieldset
         previous_fs.show();
         //hide the current fieldset with style
         current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
           step: function(now, mx) {
             //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
             //1. scale previous_fs from 80% to 100%
             scale = 0.8 + (1 - now) * 0.2;
             //2. take current_fs to the right(50%) - from 0%
             left = ((1-now) * 50)+"%";
             //3. increase opacity of previous_fs to 1 as it moves in
             opacity = 1 - now;
             current_fs.css({'left': left});
             previous_fs.css({'transform': 'scale('+scale+')', 'opacity': opacity});
           },
           duration: 800,
           complete: function(){
             current_fs.hide();
             animating = false;
           },
           //this comes from the custom easing plugin
           easing: 'easeInOutBack'
         });
       });

       $(".submit").click(function(){
         return false;
       })
       })
       </script>
```

Comment: From what i read so far it should be?:                                                                      success: function(response) { 
            $('#modal-div').html(response).modal();
        }
    });

Answer (score 0):

If your modal plugin doesn't hide automatically on clicking the register button, yes you would in success have to hide the modal, and then find the next control to focus to and call '.focus()'.  It would have to be an input.

You could also use this to [jQuery scroll to element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677035/jquery-scroll-to-element)  Scrolling to the element in view can help identify the next section if you have a longer form.